# How do I POST this data to an http server?

Tags: post

In order to control a web service I'm using, I need to send a POST request of the following data.  How would I format this into html that sends the POST request when there's a click event or button press?

```
 <sci_request version="1.0">
  <data_service>
    <targets>
      <device id="00000000-00000000-90A2DAFF-FF050000"/>
    </targets>
    <requests>
      <device_request target_name="myTarget"> 
        my payload string
      </device_request>
   </requests>
  </data_service>
```

Here's the jquery code I'm trying to execute this from:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){$.post('--SERVER--', {--THE POST OF INFO FROM ABOVE--});});
```

Comment: What have you tried? We don't just write code for you, we help you fix the code you've written.

Comment: Added what I have written so far.  Just not sure how to condense the xml into a POST.

Comment: Just send it as a string, and use an XML parser in the server script.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick an HTML node and get its code as string by using `.html()` (the parent itself won't be included). Then turn that into an XML document using `$.parseXML()`.

Note that the unclosed node `sci_request` is problematic and should have a closing element. jQuery will fail to parse to XML if it's missing. You can circumvent the entire issue by parsing a string of the complete XML structure instead of having it in the HTML document for the user.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cn3Pv/