# jquery $.post post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

this is my post method :(Code is as per tutorial )

```
 $.post('test.htm',{name:test_name"}, function (data) {
        $('#feedback').html(data);
        });
```

I want to append'name' parameter on test.html .and then retrieve complete data on index.html page

Test.html

```
<body>
   <div> welcome + //How to append name here ?? </div>
</body>
```

I can do it on php by `"$_POST"` command .... whats the alternative of it on HTML page ..

Final data will be display in index.htm

```
<body>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Go" />
    <div id="feedback">    </div>

</body>
```

Similar Posts:

[How do I POST this data to an http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674237/how-do-i-post-this-data-to-an-http-server)
[jQuery post not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207620/jquery-post-not-returning-data)
[Jquery Post Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617750/jquery-post-data)
[jQuery - Redirect with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data)

Comment: [name:test_name"] is invalid. you sure you didn't mean to send an object? {name:"test_name"}

Comment: ok , I edited the post .. Code was as per tutorial

Answer (score 3):

`$.post` accepts an object to be passed to the server, like so

```
$.post('test.htm', {name: "test_name"}, function (data) {
    $('#feedback').html(data);
});
```

of course, in a `.htm` page there is nothing to catch the request, you'll need a serverside language of some sort.

Comment: is there any way to append "name" on HTML language ??

Comment: Not unless you use a serverside language to catch the POST request.

Comment: hmm ..like php / asp ..?

Comment: Yes, like one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$.post('test.htm', {name: "test_name"}, function (data) {
    $('#feedback').html(data);
});
```

Or you could use jQuery's full `$.ajax` function

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test.htm',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'html',
   cache: false,
   data: 'name=test_name',
   error: function (e){

   },
   success: function (data){
      $('#feedback').html(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: How to append name to test.html ?

Comment: The data, in this case, will be displayed in an element that has the id="feedback"

Comment: yes. thats seperate thing . I edited my post for that